# How to pass parameters to scheduled .Net lambda functions using serverless framework?

Tags: .net, lambda, serverless-framework

I'm using the serverless framework to deploy a scheduled AWS Lambda function, using a Cloudwatch event to trigger the function.  The scheduling of the function is working as expected, but I would also like to be able to pass parameters with the event.  The serverless config is similar to the following...

```
functions:
  myFunction:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - eventBridge:
          schedule: rate(10 minutes)
          input:
            key1: value1
```

My question is how to receive the event parameter in the function handler.  The function is implemented in C# and uses the AWS ScheduledEvent class to receive the event in the function handler as follows...

```
public void FunctionHandler(ScheduledEvent scheduledEvent, ILambdaContext context)
{
}
```

But the `scheduledEvent` does not include the "key1" parameter anywhere, so where did it go, and should it be received by the function handler?
Any help appreciated!

Comment: Were you able to get any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue while using `event -> schedule`. The input properties are included in the event argument passed to your handler function:

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - schedule:
          rate: cron(* * * * * *)    // for every minute
          input:
            email: "true"
```

Here you can simply access your input param email via event object as below:

```
module.exports.hello = async (event) {
  const { email } = event
  ... do some other stuff ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution using a 'schedule' rather than 'eventBridge' event.

```
events:
  - schedule: 
      rate: cron(1 12 ? * MON *) # every monday @ 12:01
      enabled: true
      input:
        SomeParameter: SomeValue
```

Then define a class to receive the parameter...

```
public class EventParameters
{
    public string SomeParameter { get; set; }
}
```

Then the handler function receives the parameter class...

```
public async Task FunctionHandler(EventParameters eventParameters, ILambdaContext context)
{
}
```